# XML preserving structure

Tags: c#, xml

I'm doing a manipulation on an XML file, the original file has lots of comments such as:

```
<!-- Type: This is a comment-->
```

Now I need to modify some attributes in this XML file, I read it in as without comments as:

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.IgnoreComments = true;
XmlReader readers = XmlReader.Create(path, readerSettings);
```

Now when I try to modify this file and save it back the files have the comments removed, because originally I read it without comments. But if I'm to put in production the requirement is to have the original comments in the file. Whats the best way of doing this.

Now I can pass in two references one with comments and one without comments, do the manipulation on the XML without comments and modify on the XML with reference with comments. Any other idea's

**EDIT**

```
<Node1 someattribute>
  <childnode someattr1="value1" someattr2="Food" />
</Node1
<!-- Type: This is a comment1-->
<!-- Type: This is a comment2-->
<!-- Type: This is a comment3-->
<Node2 someattribute>
    <childnode someattr1="value1" someattr2="Book" />
</Node2>
<!-- Type: This is a comment1-->
<!-- Type: This is a comment2-->
<!-- Type: This is a comment3-->
```

Here if you see I have Node1, and sometimes instead of XPATH I want to jump directly to node one, currently I'm doing using:

```
node.PreviousSibling;
node.NextSibling;
```

So in this way I can either jump directly to the nextnode or to the previous node if required

Comment: Why not read it in with comments, and work on the document with comments?

Comment: It requires extra coding, when I do a nextSibling, I have to always test if it's a comment or not, so just trying to avoid the extra coding. Keeping this as my last option.

Comment: Don't use `XmlReader` directly. It's not supposed to be used directly 99% of the time - it's the basis for higher-level tools. Work with `XDocument` instead.

Comment: It's going to require extra code anyway. Either to check for comments, or to re-insert them after processing. The first case is probably the least complex.

Comment: NextSibling is the wrong approach because you should test the element name then as well. Use Select and xpath queries to find the elements that need to be changed.

Comment: "It requires extra coding," Of course it does. Could you imagine any solution to this to not require extra coding??

Comment: Can you show some example XML and code to explain what it is you're trying to modify and why reading with the comments makes this difficult? This should be straightforward with or without comments using `XDocument`.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: Xpath/Select queries are an option and am using it in some parts of my project. But sometimes I really need to test the next node, hence I was using nextSibling so ran into this comments. I'm using do/while loops at the moment to skip them and get the next node, but maybe will have to move to XDocument.

Comment: @CharlesMager: updated

Comment: Thanks. Can you add some more to show how and why you're using  `NextSibling`? A [mcve] that shows some manipulation would be useful. At the moment, the only suggestion is 'don't use it', but it's hard to explain what the alternative might be.

Comment: @CharlesMager: I have made the change. Let's say I'm at `Node1`, and want to do a test my next node which is `Node2` if `someattr2` is a `Food`, in this case I do a nextsibling to jump to the next node and do the test

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one :

```
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("old.xml");
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("new.xml");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment)
            {
                // Do your stuff here!
            }

            writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
        }

        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
```